# Given a slider div that contains slides, how can I go to scroll to the next slide on click?

Tags: jquery, html

So I have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51fduyL7/). I essentially have this structure:

```
<div class="slider">
     <div class="slides">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

How can I scroll to the next slide when I click the slides using JQuery? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have tried anything yet? What about `element.scrollLeft()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  
$(function(){
        $('div.arrow-button button.next').click(function(){
            var currentSlide =  $('div.slider div.slides div.active');
            var nextSlide = $('div.slider div.slides div.active + div');
            if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
                nextSlide = $('div.slider div.slides div:first-child');
            }
            currentSlide.removeClass('active');
            nextSlide.addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

```css
div.slider div.slides div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

    div.slider div.slides div.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="active">1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-button">
        <button type="button" class="next">next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```